# How to limit FTP access to one directory outside the user home? VSFTPD

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd, camera

I'm using VSFTPD to make a FTP server for the surveillance cameras.

I have 2 users on the machine:
1) User1: the user I use for everything. 2) User2: I created to be used by my cameras to access the FTP Server.
How to make "User2" when logged in to the FTP server go to /media/User1/SecondaryHDD/Camera instead of /Home/User2

Answer (score 0):

FTP usually limits the users to their respective home folders.

You said that the user2 user is only used for FTP. It should be enough to search for the user2 entry in the `/etc/passwd` file and replace `/home/user2` with `/media/user1/SecondaryHDD/Camera`. (Open the file with root rights)

Make sure though that user2 has read and write permissions to `/media/user1/SecondaryHDD/Camera`